# Angular ng-click suddenly not working

Tags: angularjs

I have this view, its loaded with ng-view in my index.html.

This is a snippet of the view:

```
 <div class="window">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="windowTitle">
            <i class="fa fa-list"></i>{{vm.workout.Name}}

            //STACKOVERFLOW LOOK HERE
            <div ng-click="vm.save()" id="btnSave" class="fa fa-floppy-o">123</div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="windowContent">

        //STACKOVERFLOW LOOK HERE
        <div ng-click="vm.save()" id="btnSave" class="fa fa-floppy-o"></div>

        <div class="windowRow setList animatedList" ng-repeat="(index, set)
```

As you see, i have 2 buttons with **ng-click="vm.save()"**

The first one does not work, but it has been working for days.

Then i added the second one for testing, and it works, very wierd.

They both reside inside the same ng-view, which has the same controller assignted to them by the ng routing.

So im in the view, the right controller is active, but only one button is working, clues?

Comment: same ids in one page bugs me

Comment: Is angular throwing any errors? Did you breakpoint your `save()` method and one of them hits it and one of them doesnt?

Comment: No errors, save() not getting hit. tried to make it hit another function, still nothing.

Comment: Yeah Hazard, i just copy pasted the button to another location on the page for testing.

Answer (score 0):

It was because i had an open angular expression in the same div.

```
<div class="window">
<div class="top">
    <div class="windowTitle">
        <i class="fa fa-list"></i> <span>{{vm.workout.Name}}</span>

        //STACKOVERFLOW LOOK HERE
        <div ng-click="vm.save()" id="btnSave" class="fa fa-floppy-o">123</div>

    </div>
```

Works like a charm :)